# Wiki Server 3 Plugins

Tags: macos, server.app

We're running Wiki Server 3 on Mac OS Lion Server. I'm curious to know if there are any plugins for this wiki. I'm particularly interested in a code formatting plugin...

Cheers, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that there are at this time.